# Incorporating OwlCarousel into a Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, owl-carousel

I've been working to incorporate [owlCarousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) into a rails app. I have gotten it working using the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```

However when I try to change one of the parameters, suddenly the Carousel doesn't work at all. It doesn't show up on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      item : 3
  });
});
```

This is the HTML generated by my rails app:

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="featured">
    <p>
      <a href="/shows/bkpa">
      <img alt="Sstl1idgz8hcion3dhcf" class="featured-photo" src="/sstl1idgz8hcion3dhcf.jpg" />
      <br />
      Show title
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="featured">
    <p>
      <a href="/shows/aadfa">
      <img alt="Sstl1idgz8hcion3dhcf" class="featured-photo" src="/sstl1idgz8hcion3dhcf.jpg" />
      <br />
      Show title
      </a>      
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need more info to help: any view code (HTML and / or ERB) that contains that class.

Comment: Let me know if you need any more info to help you.

Comment: If that's all the code generated, you aren't able to show item 3 because there are only 2 items. see if item: 1 works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `item` on the parameter list? Could that be the cause?

I see `items: 3` as an option and if you want to show a single item there is a `singleItem` option as well.

```
  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true
```

[source](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html)